# How can we use NLP on user-input text to generate relevant graphs

Tags: python, text, nlp

For example:
user: Compare sales between Hyderabad and Mumbai for the month of January 2022.
output: relevant graph showing this comparison. (say a bar chart)

Another example:
User: Top 10 products sold in Hyderabad during in New Year.
Output: Tabular data showing the results for new year, top-10 products sold in Hyderabad.

What i Tried:

- Created Templates-functions in python to query data using Pandas and SQL. Now the params of these functions are taken from Text input by user. Hence, i've Extracted POS and NER from given inputs, but it works for certain queries as sometimes some states are being classified as ORG in spacy.
- So i added these updated the same as when the discrepancies are found. But when scaling the project, i feel that there must be better way to do it.

My opinion:

- We may use transfer learning, but how should i create data for this?
- If we go with rule based system, then extracting context would help, but scaling this project would be an issue.
- Using DIET classifier type of model: Since i have worked with RASA framework, i guess using their architecture would help. But can you suggest as to how can i use transfer learning with such models? If we choose RASA then our task will be transferred there only and will limit itself to a chatbot kind of project, which i dont want as of now.

Any input/suggestion would be highly appreciated.